# How do I set the output slide size and page size using PowerPoint ExportAsFixedFormat using VB?

Tags: vb6, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm using VB6 and PowerPoint 2010 and my goal is to create a PDF and to be able to set the output page size independent of the slide(s) size using ExportAsFixedFormat.
However, **I do not want to use a print driver** - I need to use the built-in ExportAsFixedFormat (or possibly SaveAs)

For example, regardless of the original size of the slide, I'd like to end up with an 11x17 page size, landscape orientation, and have the slide scaled as large as possible (scale to fit) within the page while maintaining the aspect ratio.

I already have the code to most everything I need, including handling scaling for aspect ratio, etc.

One problem is when I set the page size using PPT code (.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeLedgerPaper) the output size is 13.32 x 9.99 instead of 17 x 11. It seems PPT has built-in aspect-ratio 'lock' and margin creations which I do not want!

Another problem is if I use .PageSetup.slideHeight and .PageSetup.slideWidth, the slide resizes but does not maintain aspect. If I control the aspect by calculating the width and height accordingly, then the page size is the same as the slide. So, instead of a 17 x 11 page with a 14.67 x 11 slide on it, I get only a 14.67 x 11 page containing the entire slide.

[image]

I can get the results I need from within the UI from the Print pane (using scale to fit):

[image]

How can I achieve this same output (to PDF) without "printing" ?

I am also trying to get this output for N-Up (e.g. two, three, four slides per page - usually called "handouts")

Comment: VB6 and VBA are similar, but not the same. Which is it?

Comment: I'm using VB6 but the commands are similar enough that I can make it work.

Comment: Let's eliminate one possible source of problems: size a presentation and save it as PDF using File | Save As. Does it give you what you expect?  Here it seems to.  I set a presentation to 50x40 inches (hey, go big or go home, right?) and saved it from PPT.   Resulting PDF was the same size.  Also, please post the relevant bits of your code so people have something to chew on.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - Yes, if you start with a Page Setup of a certain size, it will output at that same size. However, that is not my issue. My issue is that I am trying to create a programmatic way of outputting to PDF where I can set the *output size* regardless of the pre-set Page Size - like one can do from the Print window as shown in my screenshot. The assumption here is that I will not know the *incoming page size*.

Comment: @wayneh OK, that helps me understand what you're after. I don't think PPT will Save As | PDF to a size that you choose; it'll always use the slide size. But note that you can set any custom slide size you like; don't choose the built-in constants like ppSlideSizeLedgerPaper, because they DO impose margins. Use ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight and .SlideWidth to set the page size to whatever you like.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yeah that's what I've discovered so far. I'm hoping to treat the output as though I were printing it to paper, but it seems to be impossible without actually 'printing'. Thanks.